# Oracle Instant Client - with Docker and PHP

Tags: php, oracle, docker

I have a web application written in PHP and using codeigniter, it currently runs on  WAMP but I am soon moving to a linux based server and would like to use Docker.

The application has to connect to an Oracle database and currently I use Oracle Instant Client which works a treat.

When I move to Linux & Docker how will I integrate PHP with Oracle Instant Client?